# To show $ax^{2}+bx+c$ is neither injective or surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $\displaystyle ax^{2}+bx+c$ is nither injective nor surjective where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq 0$.
Can i use the following result?

> If $f$ is a continuous real valued function on interval $I$ and if $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ in $I$ except possibly at the end points of $I$, then $f$ is one-to-one.

Here $f(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ being a polynomial so it is continuous in $R$ but $f^{'}(x)=2ax+b$ attains both signs that's why $f$ is not injective.
And for surjective: for $y=ax^{2}+bx+c $, there does not exist any $x\in R$ such that $f(x)=y.$
Am i right?

Comment: Well, you should say what $y$ is. You have plenty of choices.

Comment: No, you've only shown that you cannot apply the result on some intervals.

Comment: Perhaps writing $f(x)$ in the form $f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k$ will help.

Comment: I agree with David. Perhaps trying to figure out why $f(x)=x^2$ is neither injective nor surjective will help orient you.

Comment: The easiest way is to note that $ax^2 + bx + c$ is a parabola.

Comment: You are interested in showing that the function is neither surjective nor injective. So a theorem that says that under certain conditions $f$ **is** one to one is not useful to you. But a converse may be.

Comment: @Andrew $f(x)=x^{2}$ is not injective coz if $$f(x)=f(y)$$ $$\Rightarrow x^{2}=y^{2}$$ $$x=\pm y$$

Comment: @Kns I think the argument should go the other direction. But this argument works nicely with David's expression for $f$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you complete the square, you will know all.  We have
$$ax^2 + bx + c = a\left(x^2 + {b\over a} x \right) + c = 
a\left(x + {b\over 2a}\right)^2 + c - {b^2\over 4a}. $$
If $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, we have
$$f(x) = a\left(x + {b\over 2a}\right)^2 + {4ac - b^2\over 4a}.$$
if $a > 0$ then $f(x)\ge {4ac-b^2\over 4a}.$  This precludes $f$ from being onto.  If $a < 0$ a similar phenomenon inheres.  So, $f$ is never onto.

Choose any two points equidistant from $-{b\over 2a}$.  Then $f$ takes them to the same value.  Therefore $f$ is never 1-1.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a naive approach. Put $\,f(x):=ax^2+bx+c\,\,,\,a\neq 0\,$ , so that
$$f(p)=f(q)\Longleftrightarrow ap^2+bp=aq^2+bq\Longleftrightarrow (p-q)[a(p+q)+b]=0 \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow p=q\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{or}\,\,\,\,p+q=-\frac{b}{a}$$

Since $\,a\neq 0\,$ the second option above is *always* possible and thus the function cannot be $\,1-1\,$ .

Finally, it's an easy exercise in geometry (not even basic calculs needed!) to show that 
$$ \left(-\frac{b}{2a}\,,\,-\frac{\Delta}{4a}\right)\,\,,\,\,\Delta:=b^2-4ac$$
is a maximum point or a minimum point, according as whether $\,a<0\,\,\,or\,\,\,a>0\,$ , resp., thus rendering $\,f(x)\,$ not onto.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ There are bijections $\rm\:g,h\:$ such that $\rm\:h(f(g(x)) = x^2,\:$ so if $\rm\:f\:$ is in/sur-jective so too is $\rm\:x^2\:$ since in/sur-jective maps are closed under composition.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you posted is not actually useful because we want to show the *opposite direction*. However, looking at the limits is quite useful and even more fundamental than using differentiability.

Let's take a look at the case $a>0$. Then, all you need to know is that $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ and that $f$ is continuous. It follows that $f$ has some global minimum $y$ (how?)

- Can $f$ be injective? No, because it approaches $+\infty$ in both directions, so it passes through every value in $[y,\infty)$ at least twice. (why?)
- Can $f$ be surjective? No, because it never attains any value below $y$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)= ax^2+bx+c&=& a[x^2+\dfrac{b}{2a}x+ \dfrac{c}{a}] \\
&=& a[(x+\dfrac{b}{2a})^2 -\dfrac{b^2-4ac}{4a}] \\
&\ge& \dfrac{b^2-4ac}{4}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, $f$ is not injective and as $f(x)=f(-x-2\dfrac{b}{2a}), f$  is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the graph $y=ax^2+bx+c$ of your function, and find a change of coordinates
$$
\begin{cases}
X=x-\alpha \\
Y=y-\beta
\end{cases}
$$
such that $y=ax^2+bx+c$ becomes $Y=aX^2$. This is clear if you know that your curve is a parabola, so that you just need to translate its vertex into the origin: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are related to the vertex coordinates.
Now, it is evident that $Y=aX^2$ describes a function which is neither injective, nor surjective: $Y\geq 0$, so that the range cannot contain negative values. And $Y(-1)=Y(1)$, for instance.
Reversing the change of coordinates, you are done.